# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'

Tags: python, mysql

I am writing a Python program that leverages the MySQL connector in Python. I expected the script to work. I am using Python 3.9 and I've ran

```
python -m pip install mysql-connector-python
```

just running the following produces the error shown at the bottom

```
import mysql.connector
```

```
File "/home/dir/admin/deployment/social/script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    import _version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'
```

Comment: This looks quite similar [to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634738/issue-with-mysql-connector).

Comment: I wonder if there is a version mismatch between your version of Python and your installed module?

Comment: Since there has been no reply here, I'm voting to place on hold for now. Duplicate of: [Issue with mysql connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634738/issue-with-mysql-connector)